# How to override userControl property

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

IDE: C# .net, WINFORMS, .net 4.0

Hi have created a userControl, and I want to make a property that if user control enabled is false than change the back Image to imgDisabled.jpg else imgEnabled.jpg

Please tell me how to override the Enabled Property of usercontrol and add this function to it.

```
  private void onPropertyChanged()
    {
        if (this.Enabled)
            this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.imgEnabled;
        else
            this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.imgDisabled;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override virtual `OnEnabledChanged` method of base `Control` class:

```
protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnEnabledChanged(e);
  if (this.Enabled)
    this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.imgEnabled;
  else
    this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.imgDisabled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use an event litner like this

class CustomProperty : Property
{
    public event EventHandler SelectionChanged;

```
private int _selectionStart;
private int _selectionLength;

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _selectionStart = SelectionStart;
    _selectionLength = SelectionLength;

    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}

protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (null != SelectionChanged && (_selectionStart != SelectionStart || _selectionLength != SelectionLength))
        SelectionChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    base.OnMouseUp(e);
}
```

}